# What should be the right course of action when reviewing edits on "Do my work" type of questions?

Tags: discussion, edits

*Note:* This question doesn't talk about what should be done to "Do my work" type of question. That has [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164463/216721) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119213/216721) [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60342/216721).

We all see a lot of edits that try to make the posts more clearer. But in cases where the question is a "Do my work" type, what exactly would be the right course of action?

I, personally, feel that rejecting such edits is one way to go, because

- These edits really don't add anything to the question. Ofcourse they make the question a bit more legible and highlight the code and all, but even with that, the question still remains a "Do my work" text which is going to be closed anyway.
- The only proper edit to such question is going to come from the OP alone. Only the OP can add some efforts of theirs to make it a actual question asking for a specific clarification. All other edits really won't help it all.

Just to highlight it a bit more, here is a question which prompted me post this question after waiting for long to discuss about it.

Question: [Write a java program to find duplicate elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22908321/2024761)

Approved Edits: [Edit 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4517165), [Edit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22908321/2)

I rejected 1 edit and before I could reject the other, it was already approved. These edits do not add absolutely anything to the question(other than formatting and stuff which is really not the issue with the question). I would like to know what others feel about this? Is it just me or does the community feel the same too?

To be more specific, I'm speaking about this from the perspective of an edit-reviewer. Should we, as edit-reviewers, approve and encourage edits on such questions?

Comment: The edits that you're talking about have nothing to do with a _specific type of question_.  Those edits fall into the _too minor_ category but continue to be approved.

Comment: @devnull - My point is that even a substantial edit - improving the grammar big time(correctly that is) and proper code indentation, basically, anything considered to be a good edit, won't be a good enough edit to such a type of question because it cannot salvage the question per se. Only the OP can salvage that question in such a case. The question I linked was just an example.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "encouraged"?  Encouraged how?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - By encouraged I mean, should edits on such questions be approved, irrespective of whether it is a minor or major, poor or good edit? Minor edits should/would be rejected anyway, but edits on such questions shouldn't be approved, as they add nothing to the question.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ ok, so you are more interested in it from the perspective of the reviewer and how should it be handled.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Yes. Exactly! :) I thought I meant that in the question, but guess its still unclear. I'll make a few edits right away. Thanks.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ if that is the sole point of your discussion, may I suggest you get away from the word "encouraged" as that has a matter of policy to it, and rather focus on the idea of "if I were reviewing such a post, what is the best course of action"

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Thanks for the suggestion. I hope the current version of the question is more clearer and on the point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking, editing a post that **is going to get deleted** is a complete waste of everyone's time, especially if it is a suggested edit.

- The editor wasted his/her time because no one will see the results of the edit very long and the rep gain from that edit will be lost when the post gets deleted
- The reviewers now spend time reviewing the proposed edit, and might waste more of their own time editing the post after clicking "Approve" to fix any lingering issues

However, take note of the emphasis on "is going to get deleted" phrase as that is the key point.  If the post is *possibly* not going to get deleted, either because it has answers or has attracted enough upvotes, or won't get closed, then editing could help.

If the post is going to stick around, then editing for formatting, spelling, and grammar is extremely important.  It is necessary to make a long lived post as good as it can possibly be as any question could be the first exposure of the site to a random Googler and you want to at least make the question look good, even if the question itself is not a fantastic representation of the site.

Notice that I did not focus on the "Do my work for me" type questions.  That is because those questions, while not of the best quality, may not be off-topic or close worthy.  They may stick around so in those cases, any necessary editing may be important.

So what does this mean as a reviewer?  Well, in my opinion not much.  If you encounter a review in the suggested edit queue, you shouldn't have to think 30 steps ahead as to what might happen to the post. Unless you know the post is going to get deleted, then you should judge the edit on its own merits and not reject edits just because the OP has not provided enough clarification.