# Is it fair game to vote to close "code doesn't work" type questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

As of late, it seems that SO is [flooded](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4669911) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327880/program-passing-over-if-statement-and-needing-pointer-to-object-type) "[my code doesn't work!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327928/parameter-name-omitted-in-my-fuction) [[giant code dump]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327997/failing-to-parse-c-using-llvm-and-clang) [what is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327839/overloading-operator-within-class-to-write-to-file-in-c)? [Please help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326927/mdi-child-window-creation-error)" type of questions (which are not the same as "[do my work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250989/what-should-be-the-right-course-of-action-when-reviewing-edits-on-do-my-work-t)" type of questions, IMO).

In my view, these questions do not add anything beneficial to SO. If anything, they are detrimental as they just add noise.

We used to be able to close such questions as "too localized", but this option no longer exists in the "close" dialog.

So, is it ok to close these types of questions and if so, what should we file the close vote as?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A question that says *code doesn't work* without describing the problem is off-topic for the following reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more
>   detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

As such, it'd seem reasonable to close such questions.

One might be willing to go the extra mile to debug and figure where the problem lies.  Even then, it might not be always possible to take the question to a logical end.  If a question doesn't state the problem, a code dump would rarely help any future visitors to the site.

Code dump, *per se*, doesn't help one diagnose the problem.  One needs to *describe* the problem, too.

Comment: It might also be (or quickly reveal itself to be) _too broad_, in that the only way to resolve it is with a debug-via-comment session.

Comment: Sadly, it seems not enough people got the memo. These types of questions are literally flooding SO and it looks like they don't get closed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell has SO turned into a place where people go to have other debug their code, now?

Comment: On the other hand, if it can be resolved in a straightforward enough manner, editing after the soltion is discovered, to remove noise and include some higher-level description of the problem, can leave behind a decent QA nugget.

Comment: @JoshCaswell One might vote to close it as too broad.  Perhaps that might be ok too.  I'd prefer to say that the question lacks information...

Comment: Unfortunately in a _de facto_ sense it has a bit, @Joce, but personally I encourage you to push back against that use unless the question will clearly result in something useful to someone else.

Comment: But the OP can argue that (s)he gave enough info as (s)he provided the entirety of the code and the output of the program. It still isn't what SO is (or was?) about.

Comment: @Joce Oh, please!  Entire code dump, a link to the code on github or pastebin doesn't matter.  If the post expects the readers to _figure the problem and fix it_, it is off-topic.

Comment: "a code dump would rarely help any future visitors to the site." being the key thing here. "Fix my code for me" / "Debug my code for me" isn't supposed to be a valid "question" on SO. There's literally not enough of us to even begin to have the resources to figure out what the bugs are and the edit every one of the thousands of these being posted daily.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, @Joce: _too much_ of the wrong kind of information makes your question just as unanswerable and unsuitable. "Unclear" might be a better vote choice than "too broad", but it's no good either way.

Comment: Can you give examples of what *is* ok? Presumably it is ok to dump code, then say "I've spent hours trying to work through this and I just don't see the problem. Stepping through shows the right value at point X, but the wrong value at Y, but I can't see anything that would  change it between those two points. Is there something in this framework that would cause this odd behaviour?"

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes, the example that you present would be ok.  The _problem_ in the code has been described.  It should not be like _not working_, _something wrong_, _does not give the correct answer_, ...

Comment: @SteveBennett I actually ask this kind of question a lot. Most of the time I end up answering it myself. Sometimes there is an element of debug-by-comment and those comments can be gold. Often the comment is wrong but it sparks a line of inquiry that reveals the true nature of the problem. You can say this is not what SO is for, but I say the value of SO is that it helps me work out how to do stuff, and if it doesn't help then it's worthless.

Comment: @PeterWone You should probably consider using chat more often.

Comment: @SteveBennett (cont) When I get a pompous "duplicate" markdown, often if I had possessed the understanding required to frame the question in terms that would revealed duplication, I wouldn't have even asked because I wouldn't have come unglued.

Comment: @devnull - could you expand on your "char" comment?

Comment: @PeterWone Apologies, typo.  It was meant to be `chat`.

Comment: @devnull - You may be right there. I actually didn't realise chat even existed till last week. The big downside of chat is it's synchronous. I wonder if there is a place for a sort of hybrid that conceptually bridges SO and SO chat.

Comment: @SteveBennett And how exactly are these questions beneficial to anybody but the OP? 99% of the time, these problems are extremely narrow and the solution are of absolutely no interest to the general public.

Comment: @Joce - Anyone would think you were paying for the storage. If it benefits just one other person, the world is a better place. The problem to which you allude was solved by google more than a decade ago. Arguably *all* development problems are of narrow interest and boring to the general public, which is primarily interested in the doings of the royal couple and their brat, or cars, beer and breasts.

Comment: @PeterWone I'm not paying for storage, but I spend a non trivial amount of time trying to keep this place tidy and it's really getting out of hand. Problem is, SO was not meant for this type of interaction. IMO, SO is supposed to be the place where you go for canonical answers to problems that are or wide-ish interest (one might argue that F#, for example, doesn't have a wide audience but there are perfectly acceptable F# question on SO), and "why is this value X and not Y after a call to foo" is not.

Comment: @devnull - it just occurred to me that I probably feel the synchronous chat problem more than you because I live in Australia in the UTC+10 zone, radically out of phase with most of the English speaking world. Chat is probably a lot more useful when most of the talent is awake.

Comment: @Joce - I tend to agree, hence my wondering at the viability of a sort of asynch chat, a hybrid of SO and chat. But I think you should look at the cost of *not* doing the gardening you find so taxing. Suppose you didn't do it. What problem would that cause, give the wide availability of very good soft query engines? SO already has an answer-ranking mechanism. A minor tweak to google could use that when ranking results, and I would be very surprised if that isn't already in place. This would produce very good and completely automated crap filtering.

Comment: @PeterWone Don't be tempted to think that chat wouldn't be useful given your time zone.  Remember, talent exists everywhere and chances are that you'd run into someone willing to help.

Comment: @PeterWone Maybe you're right and I should move from [group 1 to group 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252077#252077). I wouldn't be the first or the last to stop giving a s**t about trying to keep this place clean.

Comment: @Joce - I get the impression that I've offended you. I hope not. That said, I genuinely believe that you are busting a nut to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Give good answers, if you have them, and don't sweat the little stuff. If you think a question is stupid or lazy, ignore it. If you think it's a good question, then vote it up, answer it, give a duplicate xref answer. If the question is excellent but the language is too horrible to contemplate, rewrite. It will all come out in the wash.