# How to handle edit review of a low quality question

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Considering these edit reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6794090 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6794107

The questions are poor, as I one question has 2 votes to close it. The edits do improve the questions but they are poor questions that will soon be deleted. So I want to reject them and explain to the editors that edits to a poor question are a waste of time. However most of the available close reasons are not applicable, the remaining one is the only one that allows a comment to be added but it is titled "causes harm". The edit is not bad, but it is not harmful.

This question seems relevant but it does not say what reject reason to use: [Is "don't polish turds" a valid edit rejection reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155961/is-dont-polish-turds-a-valid-edit-rejection-reason)

The comment by @codeMagic on this post suggests using a custom reason, but the only custom reason now available is "causes harm", which I believe is not applicable. See [How to handle good edits to unsalvageable posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256078/how-to-handle-good-edits-to-unsalvageable-posts)

This question is on the same topic but has no clear view on what reject reason to use: [What should be the right course of action when reviewing edits on "Do my work" type of questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250989/what-should-be-the-right-course-of-action-when-reviewing-edits-on-do-my-work-t)

Answer (score 18):

The edits are only marginally better than the original questions, so if you think that "No improvement whatsoever" fits, then use it. Otherwise, approve.

Personally, I would improve the first review, because the body of the question directly references the title which is not a good form.

Approving the second review is ok, because you don't know what might happen to the question. If it is closed and deleted the editor will lose the +2 rep. If it is migrated it is still good, because users on the new site are presented with a better formatted version. If it stays there (either closed or not), the edit will ensure that future readers are not aggravated by the style.

If you feel charitable, improving the question finishes the review so that other reviewers don't have to go through it.

Also, it is a good thing to improve the post before closing, so that when the question is closed a later edit by somebody other than the OP won't push the question into the reopen queue without reason (marginal edit). I assume that OP would make a more substantial edit.

Comment: +1 because of the note on losing +2 rep. If they're paying attention to their rep, they'll notice it's lower than it should be, and investigate why, and see that their edit got deleted and their rep knocked down, which is a decent reminder of "don't do this, you completely wasted your time".

Answer (score 9):

Just to put a slightly different spin on things, I think there's a special case for tags. Specifically, removing irrelevant tags is *always* good, regardless of the quality of the question.

Answer (score -7):

Although "causes harm" sounds harsh, it is the option to use here.

If an edit to an unsalvageable question is approved, it bumps the question to the top - taking the place of other, hopefully worthier questions.
And the editor will never know they did something bad, instead they'll get 2 points and think they did right... and probably go on to edit even more unsalvageable questions.

So, a polite comment to the editor that there is no point in editing this question is best.

Comment: If the question needs more close votes, though, bumping might be a Good Thing.